# how would one remove a character from a single element list?

Tags: list, variables, for-loop

Here's my code:

```
def reverse(text):
   intermediate = []
   opposite = []
   intermediate.append(text)
   size = len(intermediate)
   while len(intermediate) > 0:
       opposite.append(intermediate[-1])
       intermediate[:-1]   `  <---
   return opposite
```

The arrow marked line is where I try to remove the last character in the intermediate list. Something doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, strings are immutable.  You will have to set the trimmed string back to the original string:

```
intermediate = intermediate[:-1]
```

Also, note that when you return `opposite`, it will not be a string, it will be a *list of characters*.  You can convert it to a string like so:

```
return ''.join(opposite)
```

***EDIT:***

Ok so upon looking at your code, you have more than a syntax error:

```
def reverse(text):
   intermediate = []
   opposite = []
   intermediate.append(text) # <-- this line makes intermediate a list with one element: ['input_text']
                             # you want intermediate = str(text) (cast it to make a copy)
                             # as it is, you will just pass this string from one list to another, and return
   size = len(intermediate)  # you don't need this
   while len(intermediate) > 0:
       opposite.append(intermediate[-1])
       intermediate[:-1]     # your string immutability problem
   return opposite           # your list/string confusion
```

So all together, you want something like:

```
def reverse(text):
   opposite = []
   intermediate = str(text)
   while len(intermediate) > 0:
       opposite.append(intermediate[-1])
       intermediate = intermediate[:-1]
   return ''.join(opposite)
```

***EDIT 2:*** Also, in order to avoid this kind of confusion, I would stick to only string or only lists, in this case, no need for lists at all:

```
def reverse(text):
   opposite = ''
   intermediate = str(text)
   while len(intermediate) > 0:
       opposite += intermediate[-1]
       intermediate = intermediate[:-1]
   return opposite
```

Comment: Thank you. Once I set intermediate = intermediate[:-1] is there anything else I have to do? When I run the code, (return opposite) it doesn't return the opposite of the input text.

Comment: Nope, as long as all you want to do is append the last letter of `intermediate` to `opposite` then remove it from `intermediate`, that's all you should need.  OTOH, if all you want to do is reverse a string, you can do `reversed_string  = forward_string[::-1]` http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/289/indexing-and-slicing#t=201607221640437443544 see here for more on slicing.

Comment: I am working on an assignment which does not allow use of reverse or [::-1] functions. Is there a reason why my code is not reversing the string?

Comment: Edited.  basically, you were just putting the input in a list, then reversing _that list_, instead of reversing the string itself.

Comment: Edited again, hope this helps! :)

Comment: No problem, remember to click accept to close the question!  Welcome to SO